# Why my form showing two times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to make chat room, I use jquery loader function which is re-lode the div in every second and all is well and working properly but this function also show my html form two time. Can anyone let me know where the issue?

```
       <div class="parent_col">

            <?php 
            while($get = mysql_fetch_array($spst)){ ?>
                <div class="sub_parent">
                   <div class="myposts"><strong><?=ucwords($get['fname'])?>:&nbsp;</strong><?=$get['message']?></div>
                </div>
            <?php  } ?>

        </div>



    <script>

        function refresh_div() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:'index.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    success:function(results){
                        jQuery(".parent_col").html(results);
                    }
                });
            }

            t = setInterval(refresh_div,100);
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div>

<form method="post">
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
 </div>
```

Comment: you should clear your innerHtml frst as your code simply appends the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `.empty()` first to clear the content, and then the `.html()` to return the new content

```
   function refresh_div() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:'index.php',
                type:'POST',
                success:function(results){
                    jQuery(".parent_col").empty().html(results);
                }
            });
        }
```